# Jest CLI filtering tests does not show matching files

Tags: jestjs

In some cases, I can't figure out which, I can't get filtered tests to show up in the Jest CLI. That is, if I press <kbd>p</kbd> to filter by filename, in some projects I can get it to list the matching files as I type, which is a big help. But in other cases, it doesn't--it runs the filtered results correctly, but it doesn't list the matches as I type (same thing for <kbd>t</kbd> to filter by test suite).

This has happened on Windows, Ubuntu, and coworkers have reported it on MacOS. Is there some configuration setting or something that controls this?

Comment: I had to install https://github.com/jest-community/jest-watch-typeahead and put it into the config to make it work.